# Jquery Datepicker : How to change bootstrap datepicker date change style

Tags: jquery, datepicker

hiii, I am using jquery 2.1, and using bootstrap date picker. but there is complaints from users that most of them can not understand how to change date.

> > > I can not change my jquery version, because it will affect various things.
> > >
> > > I dont want to change color theme. i need month and year change option as dropdown

so please help to to change my date picker style as follow:

I have Now this :

[image]

And Want to change like this :

[image]

or if any other option available please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [jQuery DatePicker Skins](https://github.com/rtsinani/jquery-datepicker-skins) could help you

you just need to include one of the custom classes:

Skins available so far:

- melon
- latoja
- lugo
- siena
- santiago
- vigo
- nigran
- cangas

Comment: thank you, But i dont want to change color theme. i need month and year change option as dropdown.

Comment: Ohh so you want to change just the format of the fields, not the style theme, isn't it?